# Deserialization to an interface type returns null

Tags: java, serialization, interface, arrays, deserialization

I have the following scenario:

```
Interface A{
}

Class X implements A, Serializable{
}
```

Program P1 knows both `A` and `X` and serializes an object `objX` of class `X` to a byte array `byAX`.

Then, P1 sends `byAX` to Program P2 through a middleware.

P2 only knows interface `A`. So it deserializes `byAX` to an object of type `A`. The problem is that this operation returns `NULL`.

The serialization in P1 is implemented like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;
try {
   out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
   out.writeObject(objX);
   byte[] byAX = bos.toByteArray();
...
```

The deserialization in P2 is implemented like this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byAX);
ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
A objA = (A) in.readObject();
```

Object `objA` gets `NULL` after line `A objA = (A) in.readObject();`

Can't I deserialize to an interface type?

Where is my mistake?

Thanks a lot,

Guilherme

Comment: Based on your definitions, `A` is not an extension of `Serializable`. It also needs a concrete class type to deserialize to. You can't directly instantiate an interface.

Comment: How do you expect a program to turn a dump of internal state into an object if it doesn't have a corresponding class definition?

Comment: To add on to Chris's response, I am pretty sure that you can only deserialize to the same class definition as you used to serialize.  It should have the same members and methods.  The method code does not have to match, and *some* changes can be handled automatically, such as adding new fields to the class.

Answer (score 0):

If `readObject()` returned null, you passed a null to `writeObject()`.

The real reason may be that `readObject()` threw an *exception*, which your code ignored and returned null instead. In which case you need to debug the exception. Not ignore it.